# Simplifying quadratic and higher degree expressions in partial fractions method

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, recreational-mathematics, partial-fractions

While  integrating several functions containing algebraic terms many times we use the partial fractions method, for  example consider the integrand
$$\frac{1}{x(x^4-1)} = \frac{A}{x} + \frac{B}{x-1}+ \frac{C}{x+1}+ \frac{Dx+E}{x^2+1}$$
Now, either we can re-multiply terms on RHS  and compare coefficients or for linear terms we can apply a short 'trick' like for calculating $A$,

put $x=0$ in  LHS removing the term making it undefined i.e. new LHS is $\frac{1}{x^4-1}$; $x=0$ gives $A=-1$  similarly $B=\frac{1}{4}, \ C=\frac{a1}{4}$ , hence I wonder if something similar can be done to get $D$ and $E$ .

**NOTE:** If it is restricted to be in the real domain, then I can't factorize $x^2+1=(x+i)(x-i)$
so, is there any short method to find constants like $D$ and $E$ for the quadratic expression and can we generalize a similar method for  higher degree expressions like cubic etc. all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to find $D$ and $E$ directly? Or will two equations suffice? I do not think there is any other way if you do not use complex numbers.

Comment: @PopularPower kindly tell me using complex numbers

Comment: If you know the other values A,B,C, then substituting them in, you can choose *any* two values for $x$ (not already chosen), real or complex, and get a simple 2-equation system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had:
$$1/x(x^4-1) = A/x + B/(x-1) + C/(x+1) + (Dx+E)/(x^2+1)$$
Multiply both sides of this by $x(x^4-1)$ to get:
$$1 = A(x^4-1) + Bx(1 + x + x^2 + x^3) + Cx(x^2+1)(x-1) + (Dx + E)x(x^2-1)$$

Now plug in $x = i$,
$$\implies 1 = 2D - 2Ei$$
And then plug in $x = -i$,
$$\implies 1 = 2D + 2Ei$$

So you get $D = 1/2$ and $E = 0$

Comment: got it ,thanks !

Comment: @Nikunj only 1 equation will suffice.

Answer (score 1):

An easier method to evaluate thr integral  is:$$\int \frac{1}{x(x^4-1)}dx=\int \frac{xdx}{x^2((x^2)^2-1)}$$
use the substitution:$u=x^2$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{du}{u(u^2-1)}$$
I assume You can contionue form here

Comment: But this diverges from the original question. Though I do agree that this is the more elegant method, this is not what the author asked.